# Where clause in LINQ query is not recognized in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, linq

The entity field is not recognized in the following `Where` clause.  Is the VB wrong?

```
Dim projects = context.projects
               .OrderBy(Function(x) x.name)
               .Select(Function(x) {x.id, x.name})
               .Where(Function(x) x.id <> sourceid)
```

If I take the `Where` off, it works fine. Also, if I flip the `Where` and the `OrderBy`, `Where` is fine, but now `OrderBy` fails.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: @DanPuzey - Cannot resolve Symbol 'id'

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Dim projects = context.projects
                               .OrderBy(Function(x) x.name)
                               .Select(Function(x) New With {x.id, x.name})
                               .Where(Function(x) x.id <> sourceid)
```

The `New With` keyword should create an `IEnumerable` of anonymous type. You can then work with the `id` property in the `Where` clause without having to change the order of your operations.

There is nothing stopping you from doing the operations `OrderBy`, `Select`, `Where` in that order. The above code will certainly compile and run. However, logically you need to do the `Where` before `Select`, since the former is a filtering operation, while the latter is a projection.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try with the below code snippet.

```
Dim projects = context.projects.Where(Function(x) x.id <> sourceid).OrderBy(Function(x) x.name).Select(Function(x) {x.id, x.name})
```

Comment: Where clause needs to be before the select clause.

Comment: @bowlturner - Is this only a VB.NET thing?  I initially had it in C# and it worked fine.

Comment: Good question, I just know that it's "supposed" to be Where, OrderBy, Select, maybe you changed something you didn't realize when converting to VB? An Extra pair of parentheses could make a big difference.

Comment: @bowlturner No it doesn't - I suspect the problem is the type change that the `Select` performs.

Comment: Ah yes, VB's loose typing could be to blame

Comment: No, not loose typing. The anonymous type is not declared properly since there is no `New With`.

Comment: Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

This `{x.id, x.name}` is most likely an array of object (assuming `id` is integer and `name` is string, VB would infer Object). It is not an instance of a class with properties of `id` and `name`. @shree.pat18 explained how it can be adjusted to return what you want, but I would suggest using query syntax for clarity, and also putting your where clause before `Select` (should be slightly faster, because it does not create anonymous objects from the values you don't need included in results):

```
Dim projects = From p In context.projects
               OrderBy p.name
               Where p.Id <> sourceid
               Select Id = p.Id, Name = p.Name
```